# how to develop a mobile application using nodejs/js frameworks?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js

I am new to node js,Is there any common js framework or tool to develop mobile application which support android,ios,windows mobile.

Answer (score 2):

[NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ReactNative to develop ios/android app in javascript. For more details please go through the http://www.reactnative.com/

Answer (score 0):

Go to [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org) and [Ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/). You can create the cross platform mobile apps. NodeJS only for backend, you can't create the mobile application using node.